# POST lost when submit in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony

My POST is lost during the process of submit. What I'm doing is, i get value and id parameters from select and give it to my path, because I need those information. I did that way, because I don't know how do I set my path parameter from my selected option from category select. I used FOSJsRoutingBundle in order to do that. 
But at the same time, I need to get the POST value to set my filtrer. Maybe should I just put in in parameters of my path ? But I want to know why it's isn't working.

Thanks !

My form

```
  <form name="formulaire" method="POST">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        {# Category select #}
        <select id="actionForm">
          {% for categorie in listCat %}
            <option id="{{ categorie.id }}" value="{{ categorie.nom }}"> {{ categorie.nom }}  </option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
         {# Sort select #}
        <select id="sortSelect" name="sortSelect">
          <option value="desc"> Newest </option>
          <option value="asc"> Oldest </option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="btn" value="Sort" onclick="myFunction()"/>
      </div>
  </form>
```

My javascript

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var doc = document.getElementById("actionForm");
    var selectValue = doc.options[doc.selectedIndex].value;
    var selectId = doc.options[doc.selectedIndex].id;
    var url = Routing.generate('l3o1_projet_category', { nom: selectValue, id: selectId });
    document.formulaire.action = url ;
    document.formulaire.submit(); 
  }
</script>
```

My controller

```
public function categoryAction(Request $request, $nom, $id) {
}
```

Comment: Your `actionForm` field doesn't have a name so it wouldn't be sent in the form data.

Comment: Hm. I don't see the problem with the `actionForm` because I'm using GET to get the value.

Comment: Without a name `actionForm` is just an anonymous field that will never be passed through with the form data. If you are using `GET` why are you using `POST` in the form (and also talking about it in your question)?

Comment: If you want post method then you need to your button type="submit" and  your myfunction calls from <form name="formulaire" method="POST" onsubmit="return myfunction();"> and replace document.formulaire.submit(); line with return true; in myfunction().

Comment: @herr I did what you told me to do, but it still don't get the POST. Neither the GET. I put an `onsubmit="return myFunction();"` on my form, and my button is `submit` type. Also, I removed `document.formulaire.submit()` and replaced it with `return true ;`
Thanks !

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The GET works, but not the POST.
I did this on my controller `$sort = $request->query->get('sortSelect');`

Comment: A simple `$request->get('sortSelect');` doesn't return your value? It works both for POST and GET.

Comment: Thanks @Isouza ! `$request->get()` works. It's because of `$sort = $request->query->get()` that was wrong. Also, thanks to @herr for your help !